# Create duplicates of objects and give them different rotation

Tags: faces, instances

I thought this would be best explained with an image :)
[image]

Posting a duplicate of the written text below for search engines: 
Is there a way to project an object on each of these colored faces. 
With the ration of the faces included. 
 So i can instantly update and change and place new objects on all these faces.

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this page and need an answer
I figured out that the best way to solve my problem
was to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> copy elements.
When you do this, if you change one of the elements all the others change as well.

You can then easily add another mesh to any of the meshes.
And it will then add them across all of the other ones! :)

This makes use of the "Object Data"

Which you can also copy from others just like materials and modifiers.

Hope that helps! :)